# Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am making a simple query but it is not working and I don't know why. I recently started becoming acquainted with PDO connections to databases.

Here is the code :

1. The Connections is :

   ```
   define("HOST","localhost");
   define("USER","root");
   define("PASS","password");
   define("BASE","portugalforcedb");


   try{
       $conexao = 'mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.BASE;
       $connect = new PDO($conexao, USER, PASS);
       $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   }catch(PDOException $erro){
       echo $erro->getMessage();
   }
   ```
2. then I create a a query that works like this :

   ```
   try{
       $query = $connect->query("SELECT N.id,N.titulo,N.texto,N.autor,N.data,J.imagem_noticia FROM noticias N JOIN jogo J ON N.jogo_id = J.id WHERE N.publicada =1 ORDER BY N.data DESC LIMIT 4");
   }catch(PDOException $erro){
       echo $erro->getMessage();
   }

   while($dados = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))

   {
   ```

but then I create another query in another page like this that doesn't work :

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
    try{
    $query = $connect->prepare("SELECT N.id,N.titulo,N.texto,N.autor,N.data,J.imagem_noticia FROM noticias N JOIN jogo J ON N.jogo_id = J.id WHERE N.publicada =1 AND id=numero");
    $query->bindParam('numero',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
}catch(PDOException $erro){
    echo $erro->getMessage();
}

$dados = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and I tried:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
    try{
    $query = $connect->query("SELECT N.id,N.titulo,N.texto,N.autor,N.data,J.imagem_noticia FROM noticias N JOIN jogo J ON N.jogo_id = J.id WHERE N.publicada =1 AND id=numero");
}catch(PDOException $erro){
    echo $erro->getMessage();
}

while($dados = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

but then this error appears :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: This is because you have multiple possible id fields, one for N and one for J, try using N.id or J.id in your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

At the end of query `id=numero`. id needs table alias. It should be N.id or J.id