# I want to get the total number of contents of several columns from a table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here below my code, but it error
here below the error
Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in group statement is ambiguous (SQL: select sum(d1 + d2 + d3 + d4 + d5) as total, `responden`.*, `durasi`.* from `responden` inner join `durasi` on `responden`.`id` = `durasi`.`responden_id` group by `id`)

And here below my code

```
$durasi = DB::table('responden')
                ->join('durasi', 'responden.id', '=', 'durasi.responden_id')
                ->select(DB::raw('sum(d1 + d2 + d3 + d4 + d5) as total'), 'responden.*', 'durasi.*')
                ->groupBy('id')
                ->get();

        return view('hasil', compact('durasi'));
```

i hope someone help me to solve the problem.thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274180/integrity-constraint-violation-1052-column-id-in-where-clause-is-ambiguous)

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2), consider whether your schema design is properly optimised.

Answer (score 1):

In your query when grouping by `groupBy('id')`, `id` needs table alias. It should be `responden.id`

Comment: @user11974734 Glad i could help.If this helped you accepting the answer would be highly appreciated since it will help to increase my reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

this happens when multiple tables share a column name, you have to mention the table name before the id in group by like below

```
$durasi = DB::table('responden')
            ->join('durasi', 'responden.id', '=', 'durasi.responden_id')
            ->select(DB::raw('sum(d1 + d2 + d3 + d4 + d5) as total'), 'responden.*', 'durasi.*')
            ->groupBy('responden.id')
            ->get();

    return view('hasil', compact('durasi'));
```